# Using Javascript Array filter get all the matched classes from the array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to retrieve all the objects from the `classes` array where `coachId === 2` using `filter` or any ES6 functions.

Example input:

```
let arr = 
[
 {
  name: "boo",
  schedule: {
    classes: [ {coachId: 1}, {coachId: 2}, {coachId: 3}]
  }
 },
 {
  name: "foo",
  schedule: {
    classes : [ {coachId: 1}, {coachId: 2}, {coachId: 4}]
  }
 }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[ 
  [ {coachId: 2}], 
  [ {coachId: 2}] 
]
```

Comment: Okay, we have some code now. But what's the expected output? What does `I want all the classes` mean? Do you want an array of classes? All classes concatenated?

Comment: I want array of classes @Jeremy Thille

Comment: So you want `[ [{coachId: 1},{coachId: 2}, {coachId: 3}], [{coachId: 1},{coachId: 2}, {coachId: 3}] ]` ? An array of arrays? Is that the desired output? `I want array of classes` is still unclear. _Explicitely_ write the desired output structure.

Comment: I want output like [  [ { coachId: 2}], [ {coachId: 2}] ]. @Jeremy Thille

Comment: So! Now you're talking :) That just made the two current answers invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
const arr = 
[
 {
  name: "boo",
  schedule: {
    classes: [ {coachId: 1}, {coachId: 2}, {coachId: 3}]
  }
 },
 {
  name: "bar",
  schedule: {
    classes : [ {coachId: 1}, {coachId: 4}]
  }
 }, 
 {
  name: "foo",
  schedule: {
    classes : [ {coachId: 1}, {coachId: 2}, {coachId: 4}]
  }
 }
]

console.log(arr.reduce((result, item) => {
  result = [...result, ...item.schedule.classes.filter(classItem => classItem.coachId === 2)];
  return result;
}, []));
```

Comment: I want only matched objects  having coachId is 2 from the classes array. your code is wrong.

Comment: His code is wrong because there is no way you tell use _exactly_ the desired output structure. All we have is `I want array of classes`.

Comment: Now see OP's comment above : I want output like `[ [ { coachId: 2}], [ {coachId: 2}] ]`

Comment: Updated my answer. Result is slight different, the classes aren't wrapped in an additional array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = 
[
 {
  name: "boo",
  schedule: {
 classes: [ {coachId: 1}, {coachId: 2}, {coachId: 3}]
  }
 },
 {
  name: "foo",
  schedule: {
 classes : [ {coachId: 1}, {coachId: 2}, {coachId: 4}]
  }
 }
];

var employeeId = 2;
var finalArr = arr.map(item => { 
 item.schedule.classes = item.schedule.classes.map(cls => { 
        cls.coachId = employeeId; 
        return cls; 
    });
    return item;
});
console.log(finalArr);
```

EDIT:

```
var employeeId = 2;
var finalArr = [];
arr.forEach(item => { 
    var classes = item.schedule.classes.map(cls => { 
        cls.coachId = employeeId; 
        return cls; 
    });
    finalArr = finalArr.concat(classes);
});
console.log(finalArr);
```

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>"`

Comment: It works, but we still don't know what OP wants. All we know is that they want `array of classes`.

Comment: Now see OP's comment above : I want output like `[ [ { coachId: 2}], [ {coachId: 2}] ]`